# User authorization in Java using Spring, Swing and SQLite

Tags: java, spring, swing, sqlite, authentication

I am create Java Swing application using Spring. I am creating two user one admin second general. There are mainly five function or menu button in my application.

For admin user I want to show all five menu button, and for general user only four.

I have created logging window, getting username and password from SQLite.

I searched on the web and found Apache Shiro and JAAS. But I have to do this urgently, and to use that framework will need more time.

Is there any simple Java code to do this? Any example similar to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to look very far ,
you just need to query is it type 1 or type 2 user using simple table column mechnism and hide not necessary components